# Use OpenId and create global account that can register with multiple *.stackoverflow.com subdomains

Tags: feature-request

Using an OpenID registration for each site, entering the profile information, etc., is a cumbersome process. Is there any way of registering with the various sections, only filling out one profile, and simply select "add this to my registered SO sites?"

Having a list of registered sites in profile information (or elsewhere) for management (remove registration, check current questions, etc., like a *dashboard* interface) would be nice too.

I've used this site for finding answers to questions for quite a while now, but the feature set has gotten so wonderful that I have no choice but to add this to my list of accounts. Seems like, with all the different SO sections here, dealing with all the different ones would be cumbersome without some form of dashboard.

If my "noob-ness" has caused me to miss a feature, please forgive me and point me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you register on a new site, if you use the same openid as you used on another site, the system will auto-associate your account.  This means that your profile details will be copied over automatically for you.

There is an [accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/165150/tonehog?tab=accounts) tab in your [profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/165150/tonehog) that lists all of the sites in the network that you have registered on.

In addition, if you ever make a change to your profile, you can go to the bottom of your accounts tab in your profile and choose to copy your profile to your other associated accounts.